# play rtsp url via Darwin Streaming Server?

Tags: streaming, darwin, rtsp

I am trying to play RTSP url via Darwin streaming server . they play their own mp4 files as provided in the setup; but not any other which is specified in the /movies folder.Can you tell me how to stream my own files.

Answer (score 1):

The media files must contain hinted media files – that means normal MP4, 3GB videos cannot be played in Darwin Streaming Server.

The media files are hinted using a special encoder or QuickTime Pro. After converting the media files with a hint track you can play them.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried VLC? It supports rtsp using live555 open source multimedia streaming library.
http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/